# How to get List array from AsyncTask "doInBackground" in Android?

Tags: android

I'm setting up a TCP multi communication, and want to get all message that response from each server. What's actual method?

I tried send ip array 4 items. On log cat show "Add new item" 4 times but at "onPostExecute" show "Finish :: " sometime 4 times or 3 times that don't match with number of "Add new item".

MultiReadingWiFiModule.class

```
public class MultiReadingWiFiModule extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<AirItem>>{
private List<AirItem> items;
private String[] ipList;
private OnReadingResult result;
private static final int CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 1000;
private static final int RESPONSE_TIMEOUT = 1000;
private static final int DATA_SIZE = 7;
private static final String TAG = "Reading";

public MultiReadingWiFiModule(String[]ipList){
    this.ipList = ipList;
}

public void startReading(){
    this.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
}

public void setOnReadingResult(OnReadingResult result){
    this.result = result;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    Log.w(TAG, "Start reading IP list :: "+ Arrays.toString(ipList));
    items = new ArrayList<>(); //Initial air items
}

@Override
protected List<AirItem> doInBackground(String... strings) {
    // Start Threads which read WiFi module from ip list
    Thread[] scanThreads = new Thread[ipList.length];
    for (int i=0; i<scanThreads.length; i++){
        scanThreads[i] = startIPScanThread(ipList[i]);
    }
    // Wait for threads to finish
    Log.w(TAG, "Waiting for Threads...");
    int count = 0;
    for (Thread t : scanThreads){
        try {
            if (t != null){
                t.join();
            }
        }catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        count++; //Count ip test finish
        publishProgress(count*100/ipList.length); //Update progress
    }

    // Short pause seems to be necessary for ARP cache to update
    // More: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_cache
    Log.w(TAG, "Threads finished. "+count);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return items;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<AirItem> items) {
    super.onPostExecute(items);

    for (AirItem i : items){
        Log.w(TAG, "Finish :: "+i.getIp());
    }

    if (result!=null){
        result.onFinish(items);
    }

}

private Thread startIPScanThread(final String host){
    final Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Declare result object
            Log.w(TAG, "Try connect "+host);
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket();
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, Constant.PORT), CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
                // Create PrintWriter object for sending messages to server.
                PrintWriter outWrite = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
                //Send message
                outWrite.print(Constant.SCAN_INFO+","); //Request status
                outWrite.flush();
                Log.w(TAG, "Send request success!");
                //Create object for receiving message response from server.
                InputStreamReader inputStream = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
                //Read response message
                StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("");
                int i=0; String[]buffer = new String[Constant.BUFF_MAX];
                long start = System.currentTimeMillis(); boolean timeout = false;
                while (!timeout){
                    timeout = !((System.currentTimeMillis() - start)<RESPONSE_TIMEOUT);
                    //Convert int to char
                    char data = (char)inputStream.read();
                    //Check syntax ',' mean ending each word. So Server must send Ex: Hello,You
                    if (data==','){
                        buffer[i] = s.toString(); ///Add message to String array
                        s = new StringBuilder(""); ///Clear string
                        i++;
                    }else {
                        s.append(data); //Create word string
                    }
                    //Check InputSteam read finish
                    if (!inputStream.ready()) {
                        buffer = i > 0 ? Arrays.copyOf(buffer, i) : new String[]{s.toString()}; //Re-size buffer
                        Log.w(TAG, "Server response :: " + Arrays.toString(buffer));

                        if (buffer.length >= DATA_SIZE) {
                            Log.w(TAG, "Add new item");
                            //Show only read success
                            items.add(new AirItem(host, buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2], buffer[4], buffer[5], buffer[6], buffer[9]));
                        }
                        break; //Out of loop
                    }
                }

                socket.close(); //Disconnect server
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
    return t;
}


interface OnReadingResult{
    void onFinish(List<AirItem> itemsSuccess);
}
}
```

On Log cat

```
   12-25 18:49:21.619 18842-18842/com.apyeng.tasakicentral W/Reading: Start 
   reading IP list :: [192.168.1.204, 192.168.1.202, 192.168.1.205, 192.168.1.203]
   12-25 18:49:21.630 18842-21156/com.apyeng.tasakicentral W/Reading: Waiting for Threads...
   12-25 18:49:21.957 18842-21159/com.apyeng.tasakicentral W/Reading: Add new item :: 192.168.1.205
   12-25 18:49:21.959 18842-21157/com.apyeng.tasakicentral W/Reading: Add new item :: 192.168.1.204
   12-25 18:49:21.960 18842-21158/com.apyeng.tasakicentral W/Reading: Add new item :: 192.168.1.202
   12-25 18:49:21.962 18842-21160/com.apyeng.tasakicentral W/Reading: Add new item :: 192.168.1.203
   12-25 18:49:21.963 18842-21156/com.apyeng.tasakicentral W/Reading: Threads finished. 4
   12-25 18:49:22.966 18842-18842/com.apyeng.tasakicentral W/Reading: 
   Finish :: 192.168.1.205
   Finish :: 192.168.1.204
   Finish :: 192.168.1.202
   Finish :: 192.168.1.203
   12-25 18:49:31.278 18842-18842/com.apyeng.tasakicentral W/Reading: Start reading IP list :: [192.168.1.203, 192.168.1.205, 192.168.1.202, 192.168.1.204]
   12-25 18:49:31.291 18842-21448/com.apyeng.tasakicentral W/Reading: Waiting for Threads...
   12-25 18:49:31.598 18842-21449/com.apyeng.tasakicentral W/Reading: Add new item :: 192.168.1.203
   12-25 18:49:31.598 18842-21452/com.apyeng.tasakicentral W/Reading: Add new item :: 192.168.1.204
   12-25 18:49:31.600 18842-21450/com.apyeng.tasakicentral W/Reading: Add new item :: 192.168.1.205
   12-25 18:49:31.606 18842-21451/com.apyeng.tasakicentral W/Reading: Add new item :: 192.168.1.202
   12-25 18:49:31.607 18842-21448/com.apyeng.tasakicentral W/Reading: Threads finished. 4
   12-25 18:49:32.609 18842-18842/com.apyeng.tasakicentral W/Reading: Finish :: 192.168.1.203
   Finish :: 192.168.1.205
   Finish :: 192.168.1.202
```

Comment: ArrayList ( `items` ) is not synchronized yet in your thread implementation ( `startIPScanThread` ) you are manipulating it ( `add` ) which could lead to unpredictable results.  Look at `Collections.synchronizedList` and wrap it around your `items`.

Comment: the problem arises as all parallel threads are trying to access the 'items' at the same time, to remove this problem you need to synchronize the threads or use another data instead of ArrayList like vectors which are thread safe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way to do this task is by replacing the ArrayList with vectors as vectors as thread safe.

Try the code below, I created a synchronized function for adding items int the List(this is another alternative if not using vectors)

```
public class MultiReadingWiFiModule extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<AirItem>>{
private List<AirItem> items;
private String[] ipList;
private OnReadingResult result;
private static final int CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 1000;
private static final int RESPONSE_TIMEOUT = 1000;
private static final int DATA_SIZE = 7;
private static final String TAG = "Reading";

public MultiReadingWiFiModule(String[]ipList){
    this.ipList = ipList;
}

public void startReading(){
     this.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
}

public void setOnReadingResult(OnReadingResult result){
     this.result = result;
 }

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    Log.w(TAG, "Start reading IP list :: "+ 
    Arrays.toString(ipList));
     items = new ArrayList<>(); //Initial air items
}

@Override
 protected List<AirItem> doInBackground(String... strings) {
     // Start Threads which read WiFi module from ip list
    Thread[] scanThreads = new Thread[ipList.length];
    for (int i=0; i<scanThreads.length; i++){
    scanThreads[i] = startIPScanThread(ipList[i]);
}
// Wait for threads to finish
Log.w(TAG, "Waiting for Threads...");
int count = 0;
for (Thread t : scanThreads){
    try {
        if (t != null){
            t.join();
        }
    }catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    count++; //Count ip test finish
    publishProgress(count*100/ipList.length); //Update progress
   }

// Short pause seems to be necessary for ARP cache to update
// More: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_cache
 Log.w(TAG, "Threads finished. "+count);
 try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return items;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<AirItem> items) {
   super.onPostExecute(items);

   for (AirItem i : items){
       Log.w(TAG, "Finish :: "+i.getIp());
   }

  if (result!=null){
      result.onFinish(items);
  }

}

private Thread startIPScanThread(final String host){
    final Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Declare result object
        Log.w(TAG, "Try connect "+host);
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket();
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, Constant.PORT), CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
            // Create PrintWriter object for sending messages to server.
            PrintWriter outWrite = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
            //Send message
            outWrite.print(Constant.SCAN_INFO+","); //Request status
            outWrite.flush();
            Log.w(TAG, "Send request success!");
            //Create object for receiving message response from server.
            InputStreamReader inputStream = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
            //Read response message
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("");
            int i=0; String[]buffer = new String[Constant.BUFF_MAX];
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis(); boolean timeout = false;
            while (!timeout){
                timeout = !((System.currentTimeMillis() - start)<RESPONSE_TIMEOUT);
                //Convert int to char
                char data = (char)inputStream.read();
                //Check syntax ',' mean ending each word. So Server must send Ex: Hello,You
                if (data==','){
                    buffer[i] = s.toString(); ///Add message to String array
                    s = new StringBuilder(""); ///Clear string
                    i++;
                }else {
                    s.append(data); //Create word string
                }
                //Check InputSteam read finish
                if (!inputStream.ready()) {
                    buffer = i > 0 ? Arrays.copyOf(buffer, i) : new String[]{s.toString()}; //Re-size buffer
                    Log.w(TAG, "Server response :: " + Arrays.toString(buffer));

                    if (buffer.length >= DATA_SIZE) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Add new item");
                        //Show only read success
                       AirItemAdd(host, buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2], buffer[4], buffer[5], buffer[6], buffer[9]));
                    }
                    break; //Out of loop
                }
            }

            socket.close(); //Disconnect server
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
t.start();
return t;
}


interface OnReadingResult{
    void onFinish(List<AirItem> itemsSuccess);
   }


  public synchronized void AirItemAdd(String... buffer){ 


         items.add(new AirItem(buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2], buffer[4], buffer[5], buffer[6], buffer[9],buffer[10] ));
 }

 }
```